# Determine if React components have fully loaded (not just the DOM) using Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails

Edge case here, but what if you want to know that a page has *really* completed loading external to React code? For instance, you have React components, and you can check for `DOMContentLoaded`, however, it seems rendering is still occurring even when that event fires.

In Rails, for instance, you might need to check in some other view to determine whether or not React 'managed/rendered' input components have really completed loading and then fire some callback that's outside the scope of React.

Is there no or could there not be some custom event that gets fired when React is "really done"?

Disclaimer: I Googled my brains out on this one and kept being met with, try `useEffect`, however, this is "how do I do this 'external' to React, so to speak.

Comment: Why do you want to do this 'externally'? React my not ever be "really done", the DOM could update on user input, or maybe from websocket events, or just a setInterval for example. If you want to know when the first render is done, you could check if an element exists on the page (MutationObserver -> but this is likely an anti-pattern and you are going about things the wrong way).

Comment: @George - it's a Rails app where some external scripts are loaded in views and is loaded by Sprockets. This JS needs to live next to the external (CDN) script. The script itself is using React, but I need to be able to call it from JS that is not React. It's an edge case.

Comment: Did you come across `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'index' %>` when you were googling a solution for react + rails ? Did it solve it? I'm not familiar with rails so can't help further.